# volume of parallelotope in $L^2(\mathbb R).$

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, hilbert-spaces, intuition

Let $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is complex Hilbert space with standard inner product.

> Does it make sense to talk of volume of parallelotope formed by following vectors in $L^2(\mathbb R):$ say, e.g.,
>   $$\{ f(x),e^{ix}f(x), e^{ix} f(x-1), e^{-ix}f(x-2)\}.$$
>   Is the volume non-zero for $0\neq f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Of course it makes sense: the span of these vectors is a Euclidean space with inner product induced from $L^2$, thus you may consider the lengths, angles, volumes etc. The volume is non-zero if and only the elements are linearly independent.

Comment: It's a bit misleading to talk about angles in a *complex* inner product space.  But you can still define the "volume" to be the square root of the determinant of the usual Gram matrix.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: Thanks. Can we say something about the determination (zero or non zero) of Gram matrix? Any ideas or hint would be helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: Thanks. I guess you mean determinant of Gramm matrix is zero iff  vectors are LD? (If so, is there any way one can check whether  the determinant  is zero or non-zero)? (Checking directly vectors to be LI or LD seems to be difficult)

Comment: The determinant of the Gramm matrix is zero iff the vectors are linearly dependent. For the proofs and properties, see notes listed in  my answer,

Answer (score 2):

Given vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in H$ in a Hilbert space, volume of a parallelotope can be computed as the square root of the Gramm determinant:
$$
V(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sqrt{G(x_1,\ldots,x_n)},
$$
where
$$
G(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\det\langle x_i,x_j\rangle_{i,j=1}^n.
$$
While it makes a perfect sense in the real Hilbert space, you can use it to define volume in the complex one too.

For a proof and some striking applications (in the real Hilbert space) see Sections 5.3 and 5.3 in:
http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Functional%20Analysis2.pdf.